# how i can divide one div on two, for display text on left, and image on right side

Tags: html, css

i want to "divide" my div on two, for displaying text on the left side, and image on right. The div that is mentioned in topic about has an orange background color, and red line. It's just for show you, how it should look like.

HTML

```css
#header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.headerLinksClass {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#content {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#aboutUs {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
}

body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="headerLinksClass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="headerLinksClass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="headerLinksClass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="headerLinksClass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="headerLinksClass">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="AboutUs">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> Lorem ipsum...</div>
</div>
```

[image: How it should look like]

Comment: Any grid system like bootstrap or foundation, for example let’s you break rows into columns, which will help you greatly here.

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox.
Display flex for the parent div, create two children divs each of them with the flex property set to 1.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

.block {
    flex: 1;
}

<div class=“wrapper>
    <div class=“block”>text</div>
    <div class=“block”>img</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use divs and floats:

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
max-width: 80%;
}

.one-half {
float: left;
width: 50%;
border: 1px dashed red;
}

.one-half img  {
width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="one-half">Some stuff here lorem ipsum and a half</div>
<div class="one-half"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are wanting is best accomplished using a table.

```
<div id = "content">
<table id ="AboutUs"><tr><td class="mytext"><h1>Lorem ipsum</h1> Lorem ipsum...</td></tr>
<tr><td class="mypic"><img src='...pic.jpg'></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

with some class to define the pictures width, etc.
Also, make the table fit the containing div by setting width, height to 100%

```
.mytext{
    width:70%;
}
.mypic{
width: 30%;
/*other formatting you want here*/
/*the red line between pic and text*/
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-color: red;
}
#aboutUs{
background-color:red;
height:100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Don’t use tables unless you are presenting data. Divs for layout.

Comment: Sometimes tables are a good way for general layout. Especially for rectangular patterns.

Comment: No don't ever use them for layout, they don't work very well responsively and are hard to maintain or change later.

Comment: Recommending tables for layout purposes in 2018? Seriously? We stopped doing that almost 20 years ago, and rightfully so. Tables are for displaying tabular data - nothing else.